# deadlock occured after execute CallableStatement

Tags: java, oracle, deadlock

jdk1.6 , oracle 11g 64bit environment

This following matter is just raised after changing to oracle 11g,
worked well  on oracle 9i environment.

sorry , my english is very poor

when i execute procedure in toad over and over , working very well

but when i execute procedure by callablestatement in java
after just one execute well, not working any more!

so,  i use query like this

```
    SELECT a.serial#,a.SID, a.username, b.id1, a.sql_hash_value
    FROM     v$session a, v$lock b
    WHERE  b.id1 IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT e.id1
    FROM    v$session d, v$lock e  WHERE d.lockwait = e.kaddr) 
    AND       a.SID = b.SID   AND       b.request = 0
```

one deadlock is exist

After Tomcat restart, deadlock is disappeared

here is my java code

```
private Ss14104Ent ipchulTmpProcedureCall(String accod_dd, String accod_no) throws Exception {

    long del_count      = 0; 
    long ipgo_count     = 0;
    long out_count      = 0; 
    String errorCode    = ""; 
    String errorMsg     = ""; 

    Connection          conn    = null;
    CallableStatement   cstmt   = null ;

    Ss14104Ent result_data = new Ss14104Ent();

    String worker =  (String)session.getAttribute("emp_id"); 
    try
    {
        conn = new DBConnector().connectDB();


        cstmt = conn.prepareCall( "{call out_ipchul_list_proc(?,?,?,?,?)}" ) ;

        cstmt.setString(1 , accod_dd    ) ;
        cstmt.setString(2 , accod_no    ) ; 
        cstmt.setString(3 , worker      ) ; 
        cstmt.registerOutParameter( 4, Types.VARCHAR ) ;
        cstmt.registerOutParameter( 5, Types.VARCHAR ) ;

        System.out.println("call--before-execute");

        cstmt.executeUpdate( ) ;
        System.out.println("call--after-execute");

        errorCode   = cstmt.getString( 4 )  ; // errcode
        errorMsg    = cstmt.getString( 5 )  ; // errmsg


        result_data.errorCode  = errorCode;
        result_data.errorMsg   = errorMsg ;

         cstmt.close( ) ;
         conn.close();

        System.out.println("AAAXX errorCode:" + errorCode);
        System.out.println("AAAXX errorMsg:" + errorMsg);

  }
  catch (Exception ee)
  {
       request.setAttribute("err_Message", "PROCEDURE Error:" + "<br>" +   ee.getMessage());
       forward(ERR_JSP);
  }
 finally
{
 try {
    if( cstmt != null ) cstmt.close( ) ;
    if (conn != null) conn.close();

     }catch( Exception e ){}
      }

    return result_data;
   }


}
```

After Tomcat restart, 
"AAAXX errorMsg:" is printed in stdout.log on first execution, 
but  only by "call--before-execute" is printed  on   next execution.

i can not find the reason why deadlock is occur

please help me..

here is my procedure code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDBX.out_ipchul_list_proc(
                    p_accod_dd          in  VARCHAR2,
                    p_accod_no          in  VARCHAR2,
                    p_worker            in  VARCHAR2,
                    p_errorCode         out VARCHAR2,
                    p_errorMsg          out VARCHAR2
                    )

    IS

    v_lst_seq               NUMBER;         
    v_up_seq                NUMBER;         



    v_accod_dd              VARCHAR2(6);    
    v_accod_no              NUMBER;         
    v_color_clf             VARCHAR2(5);    
    v_design_no             VARCHAR2(15);   
    v_accod_qty             NUMBER;         
    v_prod_dd               VARCHAR2(8);    
    v_prod_qty              NUMBER;         
    v_chul_dd               VARCHAR2(8);    
    v_chul_qty              NUMBER;         
    v_out_chul_dd           VARCHAR2(8);    
    v_out_chul_qty          NUMBER;         
    v_out_chul_cust         VARCHAR2(300);  
    v_out_in_dd             VARCHAR2(8);    
    v_out_in_qty            NUMBER;         
    v_out_in_cust           VARCHAR2(300);  



    LIST_NOT_FOUND         EXCEPTION;   


    CURSOR c_ipchul_list
    IS
        select a.accod_dd               accod_dd
        , a.accod_no                    accod_no
        , b.color_clf                   color_clf
        , nvl(b.design_no,'-')          design_no
        , b.accod_qty_yad               accod_qty
        , null                          prod_dd
        , null                          prod_qty
        , null                          chul_dd
        , null                          chul_qty
        , null                          out_chul_cust
        , null                          out_chul_dd
        , null                          out_chul_qty
        , null                          out_in_cust
        , null                          out_in_dd
        , null                          out_in_qty
        from SS1ORDEMST a
        , SS1ORDEDET b
        where a.accod_dd = b.accod_dd
        and a.accod_no = b.accod_no
        and a.accod_dd = p_accod_dd
        and a.accod_no = p_accod_no
        --  order by a.accod_dd, a.accod_no, b.color_clf, b.design_no
        union
        select a.accod_dd
        , a.accod_no
        , a.color_clf
        , nvl(a.design_no,'-') design_no
        , null      accod_qty
        , to_char(a.i_str_dd,'YYYYMMDD') prod_dd
        , sum(a.item_qty) prod_qty
        , null  chul_dd
        , null  chul_qty
        , null out_chul_cust
        , null out_chul_dd
        , null out_chul_qty
        , null out_in_cust
        , null out_in_dd
        , null out_in_qty
        from SS2PROCMST a
        , SS1ORDEDET b
        where a.accod_dd = b.accod_dd
        and a.accod_no = b.accod_no
        and a.accod_seq = b.accod_seq
        and a.accod_dd  = p_accod_dd
        and a.accod_no  = p_accod_no
        and a.dec_clf = '1'
        group by a.accod_dd, a.accod_no, a.color_clf, to_char(a.i_str_dd,'YYYYMMDD'), a.design_no
        union
        select a.accod_dd
        , a.accod_no
        , b.color_clf
        , nvl(b.design_no,'-')
        , null  accod_qty
        , null  prod_dd
        , null  prod_qty
        , a.out_str_dd chul_dd
        , sum(b.color_qty) chul_qty
        , null out_chul_cust
        , null out_chul_dd
        , null out_chul_qty
        , null out_in_cust
        , null out_in_dd
        , null out_in_qty
        from SS2SENDMST a
        , SS2SENDDET b
        where a.item_clf not in ('5', '6')
        and a.out_str_dd = b.out_str_dd
        and a.out_str_no = b.out_str_no
        and a.accod_dd = p_accod_dd
        and a.accod_no = p_accod_no
        group by a.accod_dd, a.accod_no, b.color_clf, b.design_no, a.out_str_dd
        union
        select a.accod_dd
        , a.accod_no
        , b.color_clf
        , nvl(b.design_no,'-')
        , null  accod_qty
        , null  prod_dd
        , null  prod_qty
        , null chul_dd
        , null chul_qty
        , (select cust_name from MP1CUSTMST where cust_code = a.cust_code) out_chul_cust
        , a.out_str_dd out_chul_dd
        , sum(b.color_qty) out_chul_qty
        , null out_in_cust
        , null out_in_dd
        , null out_in_qty
        from SS2SENDMST a
        , SS2SENDDET b
        where a.item_clf = '5'
        and a.out_str_dd = b.out_str_dd
        and a.out_str_no = b.out_str_no
        and a.accod_dd = p_accod_dd
        and a.accod_no = p_accod_no
        group by a.accod_dd, a.accod_no, b.color_clf, b.design_no, a.cust_code, a.out_str_dd
        union
        select a.accod_dd
        , a.accod_no
        , b.color_clf
        , nvl(b.design_no,'-')
        , null  accod_qty
        , null  prod_dd
        , null  prod_qty
        , null chul_dd
        , null chul_qty
        , null out_chul_cust
        , null out_chul_dd
        , null out_chul_qty
        , (select cust_name from MP1CUSTMST where cust_code = a.cust_code) out_in_cust
        , a.ipgo_dd out_in_dd
        , sum(b.surang_qty) out_in_qty
        from SS2IPGOMST a
        , SS2IPGODET b
        where a.ipgo_dd = b.ipgo_dd
        and a.ipgo_seq = b.ipgo_seq
        and a.accod_type = '5'
        and a.accod_dd = p_accod_dd
        and a.accod_no = p_accod_no
        group by a.accod_dd, a.accod_no, b.color_clf, b.design_no, a.cust_code, a.ipgo_dd;


    BEGIN

        v_lst_seq   := 1; 
        v_up_seq    := 0;




        BEGIN



            BEGIN
                delete from SS2IPCHULTMP
                where accod_dd = p_accod_dd
                and accod_no    = p_accod_no;
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN
                        p_errorCode := '0001';
                        p_errorMsg  := 'SS2IPCHULTMP Delete::' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100);
                        rollback;
                return;
            END;



            OPEN c_ipchul_list;

            LOOP
            FETCH c_ipchul_list INTO  v_accod_dd
                                    , v_accod_no
                                    , v_color_clf
                                    , v_design_no
                                    , v_accod_qty
                                    , v_prod_dd
                                    , v_prod_qty
                                    , v_chul_dd
                                    , v_chul_qty
                                    , v_out_chul_cust
                                    , v_out_chul_dd
                                    , v_out_chul_qty
                                    , v_out_in_cust
                                    , v_out_in_dd
                                    , v_out_in_qty;

            IF c_ipchul_list%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
                RAISE LIST_NOT_FOUND;
            END IF;

            EXIT WHEN c_ipchul_list%NOTFOUND;



                IF v_accod_qty is not null THEN

                    BEGIN
                        insert into SS2IPCHULTMP(accod_dd
                                                ,accod_no
                                                ,lst_seq
                                                ,color_clf
                                                ,design_no
                                                ,accod_qty
                                                ,prod_dd
                                                ,prod_qty
                                                ,chul_dd
                                                ,chul_qty
                                                ,out_chul_dd
                                                ,out_chul_qty
                                                ,out_chul_cust
                                                ,out_in_dd
                                                ,out_in_qty
                                                ,out_in_cust
                                                ,rgi_dd
                                                ,rgi_mno)
                                        values ( v_accod_dd
                                                ,v_accod_no
                                                ,v_lst_seq
                                                ,v_color_clf
                                                ,v_design_no
                                                ,v_accod_qty
                                                ,v_prod_dd
                                                ,v_prod_qty
                                                ,v_chul_dd
                                                ,v_chul_qty
                                                ,v_out_chul_dd
                                                ,v_out_chul_qty
                                                ,v_out_chul_cust
                                                ,v_out_in_dd
                                                ,v_out_in_qty
                                                ,v_out_in_cust
                                                ,sysdate
                                                ,p_worker);
                        EXCEPTION
                        WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                            p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert value error';
                            p_errorCode      := '0002';
                            rollback;
                            return;
                        WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                            p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert program error';
                            p_errorCode      := '0003';
                            rollback;
                            return;
                        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                            p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert duplication error';
                            p_errorCode      := '0004';
                            rollback;
                            return;
                        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                            p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert other error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                            p_errorCode      := '0005';
                            rollback;
                            return;
                    END;


                    v_lst_seq := v_lst_seq + 1; 

                END IF;

                IF v_prod_dd is not null THEN

                    BEGIN
                        select nvl(min(lst_seq),9999)
                        INTO v_up_seq
                        from SS2IPCHULTMP
                        where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                        and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                        and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                        and design_no   = v_design_no
                        and prod_dd     is null ; 
                        EXCEPTION
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                v_up_seq := 9999; 
                    END;


                    IF v_up_seq = 9999 THEN

                        BEGIN
                            insert into SS2IPCHULTMP(accod_dd
                                                    ,accod_no
                                                    ,lst_seq
                                                    ,color_clf
                                                    ,design_no
                                                    ,accod_qty
                                                    ,prod_dd
                                                    ,prod_qty
                                                    ,chul_dd
                                                    ,chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_dd
                                                    ,out_chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_cust
                                                    ,out_in_dd
                                                    ,out_in_qty
                                                    ,out_in_cust
                                                    ,rgi_dd
                                                    ,rgi_mno)
                                            values ( v_accod_dd
                                                    ,v_accod_no
                                                    ,v_lst_seq
                                                    ,v_color_clf
                                                    ,v_design_no
                                                    ,v_accod_qty
                                                    ,v_prod_dd
                                                    ,v_prod_qty
                                                    ,v_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_out_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_cust
                                                    ,v_out_in_dd
                                                    ,v_out_in_qty
                                                    ,v_out_in_cust
                                                    ,sysdate
                                                    ,p_worker);
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP  insert value error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0006';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert program error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0007';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert duplication error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0008';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP other insert error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0009';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;


                        v_lst_seq := v_lst_seq + 1; 


                    ELSE


                        BEGIN
                            update SS2IPCHULTMP
                            set prod_dd     = v_prod_dd
                            , prod_qty      = v_prod_qty
                            where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                            and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                            and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                            and design_no   = v_design_no
                            and lst_seq     = v_up_seq ;
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update value error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0010';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update program error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0011';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update duplication error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0012';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update other error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0013';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;

                    END IF;

                END IF;

                IF v_chul_dd is not null THEN

                    BEGIN
                        select nvl(min(lst_seq),9999)
                        INTO v_up_seq
                        from SS2IPCHULTMP
                        where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                        and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                        and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                        and design_no   = v_design_no
                        and chul_dd     is null ;
                        EXCEPTION
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                v_up_seq := 9999; 
                    END;


                    IF v_up_seq = 9999 THEN

                        BEGIN
                            insert into SS2IPCHULTMP(accod_dd
                                                    ,accod_no
                                                    ,lst_seq
                                                    ,color_clf
                                                    ,design_no
                                                    ,accod_qty
                                                    ,prod_dd
                                                    ,prod_qty
                                                    ,chul_dd
                                                    ,chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_dd
                                                    ,out_chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_cust
                                                    ,out_in_dd
                                                    ,out_in_qty
                                                    ,out_in_cust
                                                    ,rgi_dd
                                                    ,rgi_mno)
                                            values ( v_accod_dd
                                                    ,v_accod_no
                                                    ,v_lst_seq
                                                    ,v_color_clf
                                                    ,v_design_no
                                                    ,v_accod_qty
                                                    ,v_prod_dd
                                                    ,v_prod_qty
                                                    ,v_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_out_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_cust
                                                    ,v_out_in_dd
                                                    ,v_out_in_qty
                                                    ,v_out_in_cust
                                                    ,sysdate
                                                    ,p_worker);
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert value error';
                                p_errorCode      := '0014';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert program error';
                                p_errorCode      := '0015';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert duplication error';
                                p_errorCode      := '0016';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert other error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0017';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;


                        v_lst_seq := v_lst_seq + 1;


                    ELSE


                        BEGIN
                            update SS2IPCHULTMP
                            set chul_dd     = v_chul_dd
                            , chul_qty      = v_chul_qty
                            where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                            and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                            and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                            and design_no   = v_design_no
                            and lst_seq     = v_up_seq ;
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update value error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0018';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update program error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0019';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update duplication error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0020';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update other error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0021';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;

                    END IF;

                END IF;

                IF v_out_chul_dd is not null THEN

                    BEGIN
                        select nvl(min(lst_seq),9999)
                        INTO v_up_seq
                        from SS2IPCHULTMP
                        where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                        and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                        and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                        and design_no   = v_design_no
                        and out_chul_dd is null ; 
                        EXCEPTION
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                v_up_seq := 9999; 
                    END;


                    IF v_up_seq = 9999 THEN

                        BEGIN
                            insert into SS2IPCHULTMP(accod_dd
                                                    ,accod_no
                                                    ,lst_seq
                                                    ,color_clf
                                                    ,design_no
                                                    ,accod_qty
                                                    ,prod_dd
                                                    ,prod_qty
                                                    ,chul_dd
                                                    ,chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_dd
                                                    ,out_chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_cust
                                                    ,out_in_dd
                                                    ,out_in_qty
                                                    ,out_in_cust
                                                    ,rgi_dd
                                                    ,rgi_mno)
                                            values ( v_accod_dd
                                                    ,v_accod_no
                                                    ,v_lst_seq
                                                    ,v_color_clf
                                                    ,v_design_no
                                                    ,v_accod_qty
                                                    ,v_prod_dd
                                                    ,v_prod_qty
                                                    ,v_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_out_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_cust
                                                    ,v_out_in_dd
                                                    ,v_out_in_qty
                                                    ,v_out_in_cust
                                                    ,sysdate
                                                    ,p_worker);
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert value error';
                                p_errorCode      := '0022';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert program error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0023';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert duplication error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0024';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert other error('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0025';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;


                        v_lst_seq := v_lst_seq + 1; 


                    ELSE


                        BEGIN
                            update SS2IPCHULTMP
                            set out_chul_dd = v_out_chul_dd
                            , out_chul_qty  = v_out_chul_qty
                            , out_chul_cust = v_out_chul_cust
                            where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                            and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                            and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                            and design_no   = v_design_no
                            and lst_seq     = v_up_seq ;
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP  update value error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0026';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update program error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0027';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update duplication error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0028';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update other error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0029';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;

                    END IF;

                END IF;

                IF v_out_in_dd is not null THEN

                    BEGIN
                        select nvl(min(lst_seq),9999)
                        INTO v_up_seq
                        from SS2IPCHULTMP
                        where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                        and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                        and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                        and design_no   = v_design_no
                        and out_in_dd   is null ; 
                        EXCEPTION
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                v_up_seq := 9999; 
                    END;


                    IF v_up_seq = 9999 THEN

                        BEGIN
                            insert into SS2IPCHULTMP(accod_dd
                                                    ,accod_no
                                                    ,lst_seq
                                                    ,color_clf
                                                    ,design_no
                                                    ,accod_qty
                                                    ,prod_dd
                                                    ,prod_qty
                                                    ,chul_dd
                                                    ,chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_dd
                                                    ,out_chul_qty
                                                    ,out_chul_cust
                                                    ,out_in_dd
                                                    ,out_in_qty
                                                    ,out_in_cust
                                                    ,rgi_dd
                                                    ,rgi_mno)
                                            values ( v_accod_dd
                                                    ,v_accod_no
                                                    ,v_lst_seq
                                                    ,v_color_clf
                                                    ,v_design_no
                                                    ,v_accod_qty
                                                    ,v_prod_dd
                                                    ,v_prod_qty
                                                    ,v_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_dd
                                                    ,v_out_chul_qty
                                                    ,v_out_chul_cust
                                                    ,v_out_in_dd
                                                    ,v_out_in_qty
                                                    ,v_out_in_cust
                                                    ,sysdate
                                                    ,p_worker);
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert value error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0022';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert program error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0023';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert duplication error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0024';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP insert other error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0025';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;


                        v_lst_seq := v_lst_seq + 1; 


                    ELSE


                        BEGIN
                            update SS2IPCHULTMP
                            set out_in_dd   = v_out_in_dd
                            , out_in_qty    = v_out_in_qty
                            , out_in_cust   = v_out_in_cust
                            where accod_dd  = v_accod_dd
                            and accod_no    = v_accod_no
                            and color_clf   = v_color_clf
                            and design_no   = v_design_no
                            and lst_seq     = v_up_seq ;
                            EXCEPTION
                            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update value error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0026';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update program error!!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0027';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update duplication error !!';
                                p_errorCode      := '0028';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_errorMsg       := 'SS2IPCHULTMP update other error ('|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)||')';
                                p_errorCode      := '0029';
                                rollback;
                                return;
                        END;

                    END IF;

                END IF;




            END LOOP; 

            CLOSE c_ipchul_list;



        END;


       COMMIT;

    p_errorMsg  := 'complete!!';
    p_errorCode := '0000';

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN LIST_NOT_FOUND THEN
            p_errorCode := '0000';
            p_errorMsg  := p_accod_dd || '-' || p_accod_no ||'no in-out data exist ';
            rollback;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            p_errorCode := SQLCODE;
            p_errorMsg  := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100);
            rollback;


    END out_ipchul_list_proc;
    /
```

Comment: Do u have commit in your oracle procedure ??

Comment: yes COMMIT; code exist in procedure

Comment: look at the trace file on the oracle server that will have the details of the deadlock.  Note that a blocking lock is not the same as a deadlock.  If oracle detects a deadlock, it will kill one of the sessions after a period of time.

Comment: Can you share the oracle procedure ???

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have COMMIT in your procedure, you may need to add

```
conn.commit();
```

after your statement call before the connection is closed to explicitly commit to the jdbc connection without relying on the COMMIT inside Callable Statement.

Also to be safe add,

```
conn.rollback();
```

in your Exception handler ... or in the finally block to undo any held locks.

Another Issue: A failure in the finally block in line

```
if( cstmt != null ) cstmt.close( ) ;
```

would cause an exception, and therefore

```
if (conn != null) conn.close();
```

would not be executed, and your application may 'leak' connections after an error and hold resources open.
These statements need to be surrounded by their own individual try/catch blocks.

Comment: I tryed your methods, but same result

Comment: Use a debugger (or trace statements) to ensure your connection is committed / rolled back and closed correctly at the end of the procedure. A deadlock can only be caused by parallel connections. , Either the connection is being left open following the method, with locks and waiting for a commit or rollback, or the stored procedure is not coded to allow parallel execution.

Comment: You could also execute the code ONCE then check if locks are still acquired by the connection in the database.